# Elasticsearch, filter not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 1.7.1. I want to get aggregate documents following the logic which is described below:

```
response = "200" 
    AND timestamp >= 2016-01-07T18:00:00.000Z 
    AND timestamp < 2016-01-15T18:00:00.000Z 
    AND engine = "01ee20db31911aaedb97c847061ca49a"
    AND (
        logType = "click1"
        OR (
            autocomplete = "1"
            AND logType = "click2"
        )
    )
```

The query is:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "my_aggs": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "term": {
              "response": "200"
            }
          }, {
            "range": {
              "timestamp": {
                "from": "2016-01-07T18:00:00.000Z",
                "to": "2016-01-15T18:00:00.000Z"
              }
            }
          }, {
            "term": {
              "engine": "01ee20db31911aaedb97c847061ca49a"
            }
          }, {
            "bool": {
              "should": [{
                "term": {
                  "logType": "click1"
                }
              }, {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [{
                    "term": {
                      "autocomplete": "1"
                    }
                  }, {
                    "term": {
                      "logType": "click2"
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I can see results which must not be displayed. For example, I can see records with timestamp = 2015-12-31T12:46:43.000Z, or logType = "redirect". What is wrong with my query?

Thanks.

Comment: Your query looks correct. Can you explain how you are sending it to ES?

Comment: Can you post your mapping? And maybe some of the documents that are returned that shouldn't be? If it's long you might want to use a gist.

Comment: Usually, this behavior occurs when sending a query via GET in the `/head` plugin. If that's your case, please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014

Comment: This is just a guess, If this is your full query, it will return all documents. only aggregation resulsts will have filtered results