# Elasticsearch : Term query returns everything

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute a term query as

```
get indexName/test/_search
{
  "query": {
  "term": {
      "stat": "REVIEW" 
    }
  }
}
```

but it returns everything i.e. all the records. Plus when i try to execute the same query in python using the elasticsearch api as

```
    print qry
    result =  es.search(index=indexName, body=qry)

    total = result['hits'] ['total']
    print "Got "+str(total)
```

i get

```
{'query': {'term': {'stat': 'REVIEW'}}, 'from': 0}
Got 0
```

how is this possible? Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Always [use POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014) when sending a payload ;-) If you send `{'query': {'term': {'stat': 'review'}}, 'from': 0}` you'll probably get some hits

Comment: i tried post indexName/test/_search
{
  "query": {
  "term": {
      "stat": "REVIEW" 
    }
  }
}

but i got 0 hits

Comment: Please read my above comment again and use the exact same query, i.e. with lowercase `review` :-)

Comment: hey, that worked! but my data is not lowercase!!!

Comment: Congrats! It is lowercased by ES and then indexed in lowercase, but what you see in the source is what you have indexed and that doesn't change.