# ElasticSearch - failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't figure out what's wrong in my ES query. 
I want to filter on a specific field, and also sort by other field.

**Request:**

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
          "_type" : "monitor"
        },
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : { "term" : { "ProcessName" : "myProc" }}
        }
    },
    "sort": { "TraceDateTime": { "order": "desc", "ignore_unmapped": "true" }}
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": ".kibana",
            "node": "94RPDCjhQh6eoTe6XoRmSg",
            "reason": {
               "type": "parse_exception",
               "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your query, you need to enclose both of your `term` queries inside a `bool/must` compound query, it needs to be like this:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "ProcessName": "myProc"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "_type": "monitor"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "TraceDateTime": {
      "order": "desc",
      "ignore_unmapped": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

PS: Always use POST when sending a payload in your query.

Comment: hi val, now I'm getting this response:
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

Although the "ProcessName" value does exists.
If I eliminate the first term - it finds all documents.

Comment: Try `myproc` in lowercase instead. It's most likely because your `ProcessName` field is analyzed.

Comment: WORKS ! Thanks maestro !

Comment: another little question:
the docs says I should use get for search:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html

why should we use POST ?

Comment: The doc is not always 100% correct. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014