# Elasticsearch match query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 4 documents in elasticsearch. Below is how it looks like

[image]

I am trying to query document only where word `Python` is mentioned in the `title`. I am using `head` plugin and below is the GET command i am passing.

[image]

However, instead of getting the document where `Python` is mentioned, i am getting all documents.

```
{
"took": 8,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 4,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "library",
"_type": "book",
"_id": "2",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"title": "Building machine learning systems in JAVA",
"publish_date": "July 2014",
"price": 59.9
}
}
,
{
"_index": "library",
"_type": "book",
"_id": "4",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"title": "Building machine learning systems in C++",
"publish_date": "July 2016",
"price": 79.9
}
}
,
{
"_index": "library",
"_type": "book",
"_id": "1",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"title": "Building machine learning systems in Python",
"publish_date": "July 2013",
"price": 49.9
}
}
,
{
"_index": "library",
"_type": "book",
"_id": "3",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"title": "Building machine learning systems in SCALA",
"publish_date": "July 2015",
"price": 69.9
}
}
]
}
}
```

Not sure what i am missing

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by the tool you are using to send the request.
`GET` with body is not supported often. Use `POST` instead.

Comment: Thank you!! It did help. I will try to change the tool i am using. Its strange though `PUT` command is working absolutely fine.

Comment: PUT with body is supported