# Elasticsearch 6 aggregations not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using elasticsearch6 for one of my project. I am simply running some aggregation queries it but aggregations are not working. It is returning me hits even when the `_source:false` in request body.

My query is like this

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "_source": [
       "id"
    ],
  "aggs": {
    "countries": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "country_id"
          }
     }
   }
 }
```

and rather than returning the aggregates it is returning me the source of the documents. I am using elasticsearch head plugin to run the query

Comment: Look at this answer which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014 (hint: use POST instead of GET)

Comment: yeah, right, i just moved from elastic 1.7 to 6. previously i was using sense, but because sense doesn't work now so i moved elastic head and got this issue. With post requests it is working fine.