# What is the purpose of _count in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the purpose of _count in elastic search? I know that I can use endpoint _search to get the data in elastic search.

Thanks

Comment: When you are only interested in count of matching documents and not `hits` i.e. matching documents themselves, you can use _count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the [`_count` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) is simply to get the number of matches for a given query.

It takes the same input as the `_search` API but without returning any hits, just a count of matches.

The Search API with `size=0` would return this:

```
POST index/_search?size=0
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 10931164,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

While the Count API would return this:

```
POST index/_count
{
  "count" : 10931164,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: I have another question, why does it use POST verb to get the data? From what I know I can use GET when searching data in elasticsearch.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34796014/4604579 (both are supported but prefer POST when you're sending some payload)