# Submit a GET or a POST to search in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, http, elasticsearch

In this [ElasticSearch document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query) it explains how to submit a query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "this is a test"
        }
    }
}
```

But a GET doesn't have a body, it's just a link to get a document.

The related CURL in the documentation:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "this is a test"
        }
    }
}
'
```

If I read the meaning of `-d` in CURL documentation, it says

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button.

Meaning that the GET should be converted to a POST? I'm confused, from a Java program do I need to submit a GET or a POST to the ElasticSearch engine?

Comment: This answer may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch _search endpoint does support GET and POST Request Type, as GET does not work with every programm. So you can just use POST instead.