# How to run term query in ElasticSearch Head Chrome extension?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can run the term query at `Structured Query` tab. As you can see the `2242 hits`.

[image]

But with the same term query in `Any Query` tab, the hit is `4675 hits`

[image]

Comment: This is the answer that explains the behavior you're seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query, **its returning all the documents in your index, which is `4675` as shown in the first image.**

Please change the HTTP method from `GET` to `POST` and you should be able to get the correct search results.